# Optimization problem in flight scheduling

Tags: optimization, network-flow, operations-research

I found this question [here](http://homes.ieu.edu.tr/ctacoglu/slides/ch08_01.pdf)

The question is [image]

[image]

I wrote the LP problem as this:
Let $x_{ij}$ be the maximum no.of flights between city i and city j.
Let $a_0$ be the artificial link and $x_0$ be the amount of flights from Juneau to Dallas.
  $s_0$ is the sourse and $s_i$ is the sink

Maximize $z=x_0$ subject to:
$x_{s0,1}<=3\\ x_{1,2}<=3\\ x_{1,3}<=2\\x_{2,si}<=2\\x_{3,si}<=1$

$x_0=x_{s0,1}\\x_{3,si}+x_{2,si}=x_{0}\\x_{s0,1}=x_{1,3}+x_{1,2}\\x_{1,2}=x_{2,si}\\x_{1,3}=x_{3,si}\\x_{i,j}>=0$

I am not sure if I have included the constraint **Connecting flights must stop in Seattle and then stop in Los Angeles and Denver**?
Have I written the LP problem correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, this is the maximal flow analysis.  The maximum number of flights from Juneau to Seattle determines the maximum flow of 3 and these three flights  can be flown, one through Los Angeles and  two through Denver.  This problem could be an illustration to explain edge capacity and thus maximum flow in a network of directed graph.  Maximum **would not occur** if all 3 starting from Juneau be directed through the nodes 1 and 2 because the edge capacity node 2,Si is only 2. One more observation, had there be an edge between Los Angeles and Denver, then the problem is a little deeper.

As such you do not need a LP problem ( which is, by the way, overspecified).

Comment: did u mean to use like ford fulkerson algorithm.but the article asks to formulate an LP. So it would be helpful if you can tell me if my lp is correct

Comment: I did not see the problem source and it seems like your lp is OK according to the method described in one other problem. All nodes are covered and all flow constraints are met.  So it is good to go

Comment: Thank you for the explanataion